# Populating a linear array with DOM Nodes by recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, return

I am trying to make a functional recursion function for recursive DOM querying in JavaScript, here is my current attempt

```
//function to take a root DOM object and use a supplied query to return all the objects below that
function recurseTree(root, query, nodeList ) {
  //run an initial query
  let allNodes = root.querySelectorAll(query);
  if (!allNodes.length) {
    return [];
  }
  allNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      return Array.from(allNodes).concat(recurseTree(node, query, nodeList));
  });
}
```

I set up and call the function like so:

```
var ulList = [];
//calling recursive function to populate the list with all children that fit query
ulList = recurseTree(nav_root, "a + ul", ulList);
```

What is so bewildering to me is that whilst the array fed in (`ulList`) never deviates from an empty array when stepping through in debugger it actually sets `ulList` to undefined afterwards, as I try to print it to console afterwards

Comment: `return` inside `forEach` doesn't do anything. `recurseTree` will always return the empty array, or `undefined`

Comment: Ah yeah it's returning from the internal function's scope!

Comment: Would a normal index-counting for-loop allow it to return properly?

Comment: Another issue is that `querySelectorAll` will already return all descendants matching the selector, no matter where they are in the children - I don't understand the usefulness of the manual recursion here.

Comment: Oh wow - a while ago when I originally started making this function I took an assumption that it would only query direct children and nothing below, so yes you are right it works perfectly with just .querySelectorAll on it's own *double facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

First the `querySelectorAll` function is already finding element in tree that match the selector. So your recursive function make no sense.

If you want to get a flat array of a NodeList you can do: (but you already know)

#### Old School

`Array.prototype.slice.call(root.querySelectorAll(query))`

#### Supported way

`Array.from(root.querySelectorAll(query))`

#### ES6

`[...root.querySelectorAll(query)]`